# Prove that $\forall \epsilon>0, \epsilon>a \implies 0 \geq a$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, real-numbers, foundations

I am doing a course on basic real analysis in which firstly i am emphasising on real numbers. [My book](https://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/real-analysis/order-axioms-for-real-numbers.html) says that real number satisfies the following axioms.

---

1)Field Axiom
2)Extend Axiom
3)Order Axiom
4)Completeness axiom.

---

While doing the exercise of 3) I found following sets of questions.

> $\forall \epsilon>0, \epsilon>a  \implies 0 \geq a$
>
> $\forall \epsilon<0, \epsilon<a  \implies a \geq 0$

For the first part I think like this: however small is $\epsilon$ if positive and as $\epsilon>a$ so $a$ has to be negative.
But I am unable to write the formal proof.

Comment: Try the contrapositive:  If $a>0$, can you find positive $\epsilon$ that is not greater than $a$?

Comment: i think $\epsilon=\frac{a}{n}$ for any $n>1$ will work fine,but what about the 2nd question?

Comment: What about $\frac{a}{1000}?$ Or other possibility.

Comment: I don't think the 2nd question is correct as written.  Take $a=-1$.  There exists negative $\epsilon$ (say $-2$) less than $-1$, but that does not mean $-1\ge0$

Comment: Do you think that replacement of$\exists$  by $\forall$ will fix that ?

Comment: Yes, I do think so

Answer (score 1):

If $a>0$, then take $\epsilon=a/2,$ so $0<\epsilon<a,$ so it is not true that for all $\epsilon>0$, $\epsilon>a$.  The contrapositive of that is what you wanted for the first part.

If $a<0$, then take $\epsilon=a/2$ so $0>\epsilon>a$ so it is not true that for all $\epsilon<0$, $\epsilon<a$.  The contrapositive of that is that if for all $\epsilon<0$, $\epsilon<a$, then $a\ge0$.

Comment: Sir tell me one thing , what is the negation of $\exists \epsilon < 0 , \epsilon  < a$ ? Is it $\forall \epsilon > 0, \epsilon > a$ ?

Comment: The negation of that is  $\forall\epsilon\bf <$$0, \epsilon\ge a$

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your axioms, nor can I parse the strange order of your highlighted line, but I'd prove the title theorem's contrapositive. If $a> 0$ (which by order, I guess, is equivalent to $0\not\ge a$) then the positive choice $\epsilon:=a/2$ contradicts $\epsilon>a$ (by whatever axiomatic proof you'd manage of $a>0\implies a>a/2>0$).

Comment: Please see the link i have provided below for axioms,and see the order axioms in that link.

Comment: @MDesmond Your link gave me a 404 error, but in any case your question ought to be self-contained.

Comment: I am sorry for that, also i am not sure about the $\exists$ in 2nd statement, please let me know what do you think ?( Should it be $\forall$) ( the print actually disappeared)

Comment: The link doesn't work because of an extra ]

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for fixing the link. It seems to only state the first two axioms. I think it would be better to write $\forall\epsilon>0 (\epsilon >a)\implies 0\ge a$ and $\exists\epsilon<0(\epsilon<a)\implies a\ge 0$.

Comment: @j.g. how to prove the latter one ?

Comment: @J.G.:    I didn't fix the link myself though I pointed out the problem with it.  I agree the way you wrote it is better.  I wonder if it should be $\forall$ instead of $\exists$ though

Comment: Maybe different devices of mine handle the link differently. I agree the second $\exists$ should be $\forall$. Please take my previous comment as advice on standard ordering of symbols rather on which statements hold.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, i have edited that.